# Elasticsearch Indexing and Searching using association

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-rails

I have a Provider model which has many schedules & has many services.

Provider
name
email
location(lat/lng)

ProviderSchedules
provider_id
start_datetime
end_datetime

ProviderServices
provider_id
service_id

Questions:

1. How do index Provider with Schedules & Services
2. How do I query or filter let's say a Consumer/User would like to search providers that are available within date range and offer a kind of service/s.

I am using Ruby on Rails. Any answers will be appreciated.
I would like to understand it on ES level.

thanks!

Comment: would be better if you can share some initial mapping on which we can suggest improvements

Comment: I don't have any. I just have the basic
```include Elasticsearch::Model
include Elasticsearch::Model::Callbacks

index_name "provider-#{Rails.env}"```